# Run Spark executors as specified Linux user

Tags: apache-spark, nfs

I have a spark standalone cluster having 5 nodes. All nodes have mounted the same volume via nfs. Files within these mount have certain linux file permission.

When I Spark-submit my Job as user x (who is available on all nodes and has on all nodes the same uid) then I want that the spark executors also run as user x so that the job can only access files user x has permissions to.

I don't have Kerberos and I don't have HDFS.

Is this possible in this setup? 
Would it help to use YARN?

Comment: Spark Standalone does not support authentication (when the client connects to the Master to submit a job) nor impersonation (when the Workers spawn driver & executors for the job). In other words, the Linux user accessing your NFS data will be whatever service account runs the Workers, typically `spark` (or `root` if you are sloppy).

Comment: AFAIK, the only execution framework that supports impersonation without authentication is YARN -- you just "pretend" to be Linux user `xyz` (with `export HADOOP_USER_NAME=xyz` before running `spark-submit`) and YARN will spawn the job container under that account.

Comment: With YARN + Kerberos you can't pretend, you must actually have a valid Kerberos ticket to prove your identity. But if you "are" a  privileged _proxy user_ defined as such in Hadoop config (typically `oozie` `hue` `knox` `zeppelin` `livy`) you can request YARN to run a job for any Linux account _(because you are assumed to be a web service running a session for that user after proper authentication, e.g. LDAP user/password)_

Comment: With Kubernetes, you have some sort of authentication... but you would not use NFS anyway. Rather some sort of S3-compatible storage, with Kubernetes providing the S3 "secrets" associated with the authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who as been playing a lot with Spark Standalone, Yarn, HDFS and so on.
Here's what my experience told me:

- Spark Standalone has absolutly no form of access control or regulation possible.
- Yarn without HDFS is possible but your job will always run as Yarn, if you write files to something else than HDFS the files will be owned by yarn user.
- Kerberos is not a solution to that kind of usage, HDFS/yarn works hand in hand and if you run a job as spark with kerberos and write in HDFS the files will belong to spark.  If you do the same with NFS or any other distributed file system files will belong to the system user used to run Yarn.
- Finally you might be able to mitigate some issues with Ranger or Livy but files written outside of HDFS will belong to the system user that write them.

My conclusion to such a problem is that HDFS is the centre piece of all the Hadoop ecosystem and not using it is problematic.
It kinda s**** somehow as HDFS is really complex to maintain compared to NFS.